# ElasticSearch: How do I search by sth similar to SQLs "CHAR_LENGTH()"?

Tags: elasticsearch

In (my)SQL, I can filter data-sets by [CHAR_LENGTH()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length%20%2aCHAR_LENGTH%28%29%2a):

```
SELECT [...] FROM [...] WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(`some_table_field`) < '1000';
```

Is there a way to do this kind of search in ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use script filter 
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-filter.html
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html

```
"filtered" : {
      "query" : {
          "match_all" : {}
      },
      "filter" : {
          "script" : {
              "script" : "_source.some_table_field.length() < 1000"
          }
      }
}
```

Note that using `_source` is much slower compared to using `doc`, so you can rewrite the query to use `doc`, but be ensure that the analyzer of field `some_table_field` need to return the single original string, e.g. "non_analyzer", "keyword", or you will get wrong length(), and return wrong results.

```
"filtered" : {
          "query" : {
              "match_all" : {}
          },
          "filter" : {
              "script" : {
                  "script" : "doc['some_table_field'].value.length() < 1000"
              }
          }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I tested "script", it works fine! But in my use case, script is too slow.

Comment: Yes because it access _source field, which will be slow. You can use doc["some_table_field"].value.length() but beaware with the analyzer you applied for it, which can affect the length. It's better to define a non_analyzer mapping for it and use doc["..."] to gain better performance

Comment: I added one more options in answer for "doc" case

Comment: Thanks for your additional suggestion "doc" - but still in my usecase, it is too slow.

Btw, I had to use syntax 
    "script": "doc['some_table_field'].values.length < 1000"